# Can I pass values from one Python file to another?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to run one file from another in a loop.
FileA:

cov_matrix is a covariance matrix I import from Bloomberg and rets is a dataframe also imported from Bloomberg.

max_vol = [8,9,10]

```
def func1(weights):
    return max_vol[i] - np.sqrt(np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))

def obj(weights):
    return np.sum(rets.T*weights)

cons = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': func1}
bnds = (0,6) in range 30

def minimixe()
    scipy.minimize(obj, initial_weights, bounds = bnds, method = 'SLSQP', constraints = cons}
```

I want to run the minimize function over multiple values of max_vol.

I tried running the whole program in a for loop but I get the same results even for different values of max_vol. So I tried calling the entire fileA from another file B.

```
import fileA
    for i in range(8,10):
    fileA.minimize()
```

but I get the error that i is not defined.

I tried passing i directly to minimize but got list index out of range error for func1

```
def func1(weights):
    return max_vol[i] - np.sqrt(np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))

cons = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': func1}
bnds = (0,6) in range 30

def minimixe()
    scipy.minimize(obj, initial_weights, bounds = bnds, method = 'SLSQP', constraints = cons}

for i in range(8,10)
    minimize(i)
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: Can you pass `i` to `minimize`, who passes it to `func1`?

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't work when I pass i to minimize. I still get the i is not defined error.

Comment: Please show what you tried, and explain what it did when it "did not work".

Comment: I've added my work in the question

Comment: `func1` doesn't accept `i` so it is ill defined

Comment: You'll get a `NameError` against `bnds` as well

Comment: bounds was a typo. Thanks, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `scipy.minimize` is calling `func1` with default args, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to add `i` as a positional arg and still pass it to `scipy.minimize`:

```py
from functools import partial

# add that argument here so you don't get a nameError
def func1(i, weights):
    return max_vol[i] - np.sqrt(np.dot(cov_matrix, weights))

# add the argument here so that you can call it in fileB
def minimize(i):
    # partial will return a new function with the first positional argument
    # specified already
    cons = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': partial(func1, i)}
    # now this can work as expected
    scipy.minimize(obj, initial_weights, bounds = bnds, method = 'SLSQP', constraints = cons}
```

That allows `i` to be passed as a first positional arg to `func1`, without `scipy` needing to do that explicitly. You can now call it like:

```py
import fileA

for i in range(8, 10):
    fileA.minimize(i)
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting positive directional derivative for linsearch. When I run the program for individual values that is 8 and 10 separately it works fine.

Comment: That's a different question that I'm not sure I can answer

Comment: is it possible to define cons2 outside the definition?

Comment: You can, but if you are using a variable to define what `cons` looks like, it would not be best practice to do that in global scope. Otherwise, the `i` in `cons` will be using `fileA.i` where it appears you really want the `i` in `fileB`